# Socket.io client side event firing

Tags: socket.io

I want my server.js to perform a specific function when prompted by client.html

The part of two flies are as follows:

Server.js:

```
io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {

socket.on('key',function(data){
console.log('done'); //this statement is never executed

    });
  });
```

Client:

```
<script>
      var socket = io.connect();
     socket.on('connect', function () {
     socket.emit('key',{
     string:'string'
     });

    </script>
```

console.log('done'); is never executed ..don't know why...Please help me guys..:)

Comment: Are you getting any errors in the browser console ?

Comment: Did you folowed any tutorial ? http://codetuner.blogspot.com/2012/04/real-time-web-sample-using-socketio-and.html

Answer (score 0):

Have you included the `socket` js file?

`<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>`

Comment: yeah i have included the js file @ashley

Comment: just realised, in `var socket = io.connect();` you need to specify the url: `var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:3000');`

Comment: remove `socket.on('connect')` from the client side, because you aren't emitting any sockets called `connect`. if you look at the docs, there is no `on('connect')` : http://socket.io/#how-to-use

Comment: Actually that page does use on('connect') on the client side.  Also, it is listed as one of the events emitted here: https://github.com/LearnBoost/socket.io/wiki/Exposed-events ...however, my problem is that I'm not receiving any of these events on the client side at all...

Answer (score 0):

Old question, but the reason your code is not working is because you are missing your closing: `});` on your client side code.

Solution:

```
<script>
var socket = io.connect();
socket.on('connect', function () {
  socket.emit('key',{
     string:'string'
   });
});  //<--- Missing closing tag
</script>
```